# Help with translating "For those about to die, we salute you" ?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I want to riff off the famous saying "those about to die salute you".

According to wikipedia the original is:

"Ave, Imperator, morituri te salutant" ("Hail, Emperor, those who are about to die salute you")

I want to change it to "Hail, Project Manager, those who are about to sprint salute you"

The best I could come up with is:

"Ave, Vilicus Operis, concitī te salutant"

But it seems totally wrong.

Anyone have a better translation?

Comment: Do you want a word that literally means "sprint"? Obviously, that verb in Latin wouldn't contain the meanings that the word has in the software industry.

Comment: @brianpck "sprint", "scramble", ...something that indicates effort and drive,..

Comment: To indicate 'strive', why not use _nitor_ (future participle _nisurus_ or _nixurus_)? And I don't think that _vilicus_ is quite right (unless you have a freedman in charge of you wage-slaves!).

Comment: I'm not sure there is a good Latin word for "sprint" in this meaning (which I had never seen before!). I would suggest something as dull as *laboraturi te salutant*, "those about to work salute you". If you go with *vilicus*, it should be in the [vocative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case) here: *vilice*. Perhaps: *Ave, vilice, laboraturi te salutant.*

Comment: @Joonas Do you think *cursuri* works?

Comment: @brianpck I'm not sure. If I read *currere* as "hurry", it makes sense, but it's pretty ambiguous. It's close to "sprint" literally, but the match looks much poorer at the level of idioms. At least *laboraturi* is safer than *cursuri*, but I'm not sure if it's better. Of course one could explain: *Ita facturi/acturi/gesturi, ut ..., te salutant.* But that kills all fun.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the *operis* is unnecessary, but *vilicus* is subversively delightful. It means "overseer," and was often used for the slave who oversaw the field-working slaves. I really like the connotation there.

For 2nd declension nouns ending in -us, the vocative (i.e. when they are being addressed) ending is -e, not -us. Since *imperator* doesn't follow that pattern, it sees no change, but *vilicus* does, so you have to have *ave vilice* and not *ave vilicus*.

One problem with *concieo* is that it's transitive, and therefore takes a direct object. A *vilicus* might *concieo* his workers, for example. I think you're better off with a word like *festinare* or *properare*, both meaning "to hurry [yourself]". The former has a nice Latin proverb that would complement it: *festina lente*, "hurry slowly." Essentially, do whatever you're doing as fast as you can, but not so fast that you are making mistakes doing so.

The future participle of *festinare* is very rare, but it is attested in Pliny and therefore Classical.

All this yields:

> **Ave Vilice, festinaturi te salutant.**