# Morituri - Grammar

Tags: vocabulary

Basic, I'm sure, but I've read that this form is infinitive - to die - but also can mean 'we who are about to die'.
I'm newish to Latin grammar - what is the name of the form/case(?) that could express this 6 word phrase by itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the [future active participle](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/future-participle). It is *not* the infinitive, which would be *mori* for this verb.

The reason it takes so many words to express this concept is simply because English lacks a future participle. In general, English only has two participial forms: present active (-ing, such as "these *trying* times") and past passive (often, but not always -ed, such as "*tried* and true methods).

Latin has another for actions which would occur in the future. That's the –tur- part of the word you see. It also often, but not always, indicates time in the near future: "dying [in the near future]". A common way to express that is "about to *X*".

The word by itself doesn't necessarily encode for *we*, but it is masculine plural<sup>1</sup>, which is more information than you can get from English participles. In context of a very famous phrase ([*morituri te salutant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ave_Imperator,_morituri_te_salutant), for which also see [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2891/help-with-translating-for-those-about-to-die-we-salute-you)), the subject is technically third person plural ("they about to die salute you"), but it was spoken by gladiators who went off into the arena, so the "they" in the sentence refers to the ones speaking it. This is why you'll often see "we" used to translate it.

<sub>1. Technically, it could be masculine or neuter singular genitive as well, but not in the context of the phrase from which it is known in English. Regardless, the point stands.</sub>

Comment: Interestingly, there is only one recorded instance from antiquity where this famous phrase was uttered, technically not by gladiators in the arena but by naumachiarii forced to take part in a mock (but, for them, deadly) sea battle. Suetonius records it as cited here. However, Cassius Dio, narrating the same instance, writes: οἱ ἀπολούμενοί σε **ἀσπαζόμεθα** -- which is in the first person.

Comment: [Vita Divi Claudii 21](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/L/Roman/Texts/Suetonius/12Caesars/Claudius*.html#21), I should add.

Comment: So even the ancients thought that would be a good way to translate the Latin. Interesting.